# What does e+ mean in linear mixed model output?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, notation

In my mixed effect model output, the Estimate for Intercept is " 7.141e+00" I know e- but I am not sure what e+ is. Also, df has numbers like 5.461e+01, 1.052e+02, 5.396e+0.

If that means adding zeros (multiplying) where do zeros should go?
Could anyone please explain?

+Do you know the R code to get the exact number from the given number with e- in the model output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `e` is scientific notation. It’s telling you to multiply the base number by 10 raised to the power displayed in your output. For example, `1.052e+02` is equivalent to $1.052 \times 10^{2} = 105.2$. Note `e+00` is equivalent to $10^{0} = 1$, which is just the base number itself.

To rid yourself of all scientific notation, run the following line of code:

```
options(scipen = 999)
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much!